# 2019 is coming!

Tags: mathematics

**Use $2$ $0$ $1 $ and $9$ to make the numbers $66, 74, 76, and$ $77$**

RULES

1. You must use all 4 digits.
   Only the digits 2, 0, 1, and 9 can be used. 
   You can make multi-digit numbers out of the numbers. Examples: 20, 92, 2.9
2. The square function may NOT be used. Nor may the cube, raise to a fourth power, or any other function that raises a number to a specific power.
   You may use the ^ operation if you use a digit, for example, [(9 + 1)^2 - 0!] is acceptable (if you're trying to get 99), because 2, 0, 1, and 9 is used.
   However, [20 ^ 2 / 9 + 1] can't be used to get 40 because it uses an extra 2.
3. Sorry, but the integer function may NOT be used. Nor may the round, floor, ceiling, more than 2 factorials in a row, repeating symbol, or truncate functions.
4. +, -, *, /, (), !, sqrt, ^, and !! may be used for functions.
5. I picked these because these are the hardest for 2019. From the numbers 1-100, these are the only ones I didn't get.

**Again, no brute-force methods. Good luck.**

Comment: Are these solutions possible?

Comment: @QuantumTwinkie let's find out! :D

Comment: What does it mean "more than 2 factorials in a row"? "(N!)!" or what?

Comment: @Alto Doesn't using sqrt contradict your requirements? It's an explicit square root, i.e. it uses 2, or, even worse, it could be represented as x^1/2 which uses 1 and 2.

Comment: @rhsquared good point, but I find it funny coming from you, "rh**squared**" heheh

Comment: $2018$ gives $\sqrt{(8-1)!}+2+0!=73.9929...$ but we are not using an $8$ or rounding functions... I could even do with an extra $0$ or $1$ instead, but still...

Comment: @user477343 You are quite right. Maybe I won't be allowed to answer because of the implicit two in my name.

Comment: Are bare decimal points allowed, like $.1$ and $.2$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

66:

> $(\sqrt{9})!\times(12-0!)$

74:

> $9/.12-0!$

76:

> $9/.12+0!$

77:

> $((\sqrt{9})!)!\times.1+(0!/.2)$

Comment: I think the square function cannot be used

Comment: No it can't even I tried using it.

Comment: And you can't concatenate to make $12$, either, but $(+1)$ in at least $13$ hours for the effort (DVL) :D

Comment: @user477343 you can concatenate 1 and 2. See examples above `20, 92, 2.9`

Comment: @IanFako Wait... I thought it said "**can't**" .... dammit, I would have had more of a chance finding a solution otherwise. Eh well, everything happens for a reason... at least in my philosophy.

Answer (score 0):

Also here is another solution to 77 that might be easier- (√9!)!*.1+(0!/.2)

The equation doesn't require the use of a double factorial.

KG

Comment: You should check the other answers before adding a new one. This is the same as the accepted answer for 77.